# Errors import project Eclipse

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I'm trying to deploy my app zoom in Imageview. I downloaded the project https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom but I get errors in Eclipse to do. What am I doing wrong?

**ImageViewTouchBase**

```
import it.sephiroth.android.library.easing.Cubic; --> cannot be resolved
import it.sephiroth.android.library.easing.Easing; --> cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some tricks applying for that. Such as

At first complete project download from repository. then try those tricks.

number 1#: File=>Import=>android=>Existing android code Into workspace.

number 2#: Project=>clean..

number 3#: delete folder bin and folder are both.

number 4#: check easing exist or not.(in res/libs folder)

and finally number 5#: Restart eclipse.

I am not sure but i expected you will be get help probably. Best of Luck!

Comment: #3 in library or ImageViewTestActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You have't pulled complete code.try to download complete code to fix these errors because these classes/packages are not in your project

Comment: I have imported project (library, gradle and demo folders in my Eclipse). Then library appears with errors.